# How to increase the height of textarea in wxTextCtrl automatically?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using the `wxTextCtrl` for the **textarea** of the chat UI.
My question is how to increase the height of **textarea** automatically without vertical scroll when the user types long text that is over than height of **textarea**.
How can I do it with `wxTextCtrl`?

If it's impossible it with `wxTextCtrl`, which is the best solution for implementing the chat textarea with `wxWidget` in chat UI?

Comment: are you creating the control as multiline? There is a recent post on the wx forum about this - please check it.

Comment: If you exhaust all your wx options, then you can check the textSize for multiline string (https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_d_c.html#af04e14231873e8659c4e88036f1bb8ce) and re-adjust the control's size accordingly.